# Javascript embeded image

Tags: image, embed

The fragment of the tag below is not showing.  Everything else shows but not the image.  I also the ending "==/ seems incorrect.  I am using Ostermiller encoder.

```
<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAAAAQABAAD//gB.../0sv+Up/pL/APaQHjL/AOvF4jD/2Q==/"/></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

That header "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAAAAQABAAD/" appears to be the jpg header but should it end with ==" and is the "/" the reason for not rendering?  If so can I eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo, as expected the Base64 should have ended with "==".
For the details I generated the image as a java.awt.Image into an ByteArrayOutputStream and encoded it with Base64 and wrapped the img tag.
Sorry for the clutter.